# Save user login token to browser window instead of session storage

Tags: reactjs, authentication, google-oauth, session-storage

I am working on creating a login page for an application. I have used google OAuth for the login and I am using session storage to save the token. But if I go to another tab it again asks me to log in even though I have logged in from another tab. I want to save the token for the browser window so that I don't have to login every time I opened a new tab.
Any leads regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` to save data that will be accessible in different tabs of your application. Data in the `localStorage` will be also available after you refresh the active tab.

You have to keep in mind, however, that presently, keeping login data in `localStorage` is considered unsafe. The data kept there is vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting attacks. It's OK if you're creating some applications for your own use or as a playground, but in a real-world app you would have to resort to more secure, but also more complicated setups that use backend components to store tokens (and communicate with the front using cookies).

Comment: Thanks, I tried local storage and it is working. Yes I am creating a token in backend and only storing this in the local storage.